# Generating MSI transform using WiX or some other command-line/script

Tags: wix, windows-installer, transform

I am aware of this question [Generating msi transform using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757902/generating-msi-transform-using-c-sharp) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764806/1218483). I have two problems with the answer; 1) is that our antivirus is triggered if I try to read from a .MSI and 2) I'd like to be able to autogenerate these transforms from some rules I'll set up.

I've tried to see if I could figure out the WiX toolset but haven't been able to do so. As far as I can tell something like torch would need an original and a changed .MSI file to generate the transform and I'd like to, instead, specify the properties that I want changed for each transform.

I'll not need to add files to the transform.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I could do this?

Comment: What exactly is being blocked?  Your C#-compiled exe, or the API call to the WindowsInstaller.Installer object?  Could you try using Powershell/VBScript instead?

Comment: My C# compiled exe, right at the point where I copy the .msi file to another. I'd say that is not any call to the WindowsInstaller.Installer object.

Comment: I'd prefer a non-C# solution. I don't know if WiX is the way to go, that was just an idea

Comment: Just use PowerShell then - here is an example: https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/2014/10/30/powershell-windows-installer-msi-transforms-mst/